# Simple MinMax problem over PSD matrix and real vector

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Consider the following nested optimization,
\begin{equation}
A^* = \arg\max_A \,\,\min_x x^T P x \quad s.t.  \quad \|x\|=1 \quad,\quad \|Ax\|\leq 1
\end{equation}
where $P$ is a given positive definite matrix, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is in the space of $n\times n$ real symmetric positive semi-definite matrices, and both $\|.\|$'s are vector L2 norm.

I guess that optimal $A$ has the form $A^*=c P^{-1}$ where $c$ is some scalar. Is this correct? If so, I really appreciate any advice about how to prove this.

Thanks

Golabi

Comment: What is the objective function of the outer optimization? The inner optimization's objective does not depend on $A$.

Comment: @Rammus the inner constraints depend on $A$ and influence the inner objective value.

Comment: @RobPratt Woops, yes, that makes sense, thanks. I read that completely wrong first time around.

Comment: just pick $A=2I$, because then no $x$ exists that satisfies $||x||=1$ and $||Ax||\leq 1$, resulting in the minimization problem being infeasible and having a value of $\infty$

Comment: @LinAlg any thought about the solution though?

Comment: @Golabi I just gave you a solution, you cannot do better than that.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you! You are right.